# Redirect wrong behavior in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom in my reactjs application, and I have this block at the end of my routes to redirect all the wrong paths to this one:

```
 <Router>
  <React.Suspense fallback={loading}>
    <Switch>
//...all my routes...
//at the end of my routes I have this
     <Route path="*">
      <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
     </Route>
    </Switch>
  </React.Suspense>
 </Router>
```

If I add a random route like **/nonexistentroute** it redirects me to **/dashboard** but, If I'm in a specific route like **/home** and I click on the refresh button of chrome, I'm being redirected to the **/dashboard** when it should keep me in the same route.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide a more complete and comprehensive code example so we can see how this route relates to the routes you are rendering. We should be able to see why this route is matched and rendered unconditionally. I suspect you are missing a `Switch` component. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello, I fixed my question if you can help me with it.

Comment: Your edit appears to agree with the suggested solution from my answer. Are you *still* having an issue? Where are you rendering  this `"/nonexistentroute"` route? If you are rendering it *after* your redirect then it won't ever be reachable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Navigate from latest version of react-router-dom to redirect to a different page.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Test_1 from './components/Test_1';
import Test_2 from './components/Test_2';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Test_1 />} />
          <Route path='/home' element={<Test_2 />} />
          <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/' />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try writing like this if you are using react-router-dom version 6

```
<Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Hi, in my case if I am using localhost:3000/#/about or just localhost:3000/#/ it is taking me to default component, though it is supposed to be wrong url. Can you please guide me on this?

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like you are rendering several routes into a router without a `Switch` component. Routers ***inclusively*** match and render routes while the `Switch` ***exclusively*** matches and renders the first `Route` or `Redirect` component. In other words, a router will render all matches, redirects included, the `Switch` renders only the first.

Wrap your routes in a `Switch` and place the `redirect` last in the list so if no other route path was previously matched the `Redirect` will render.

```
<Switch>
  ... all other routes ...
  <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
</Switch>
```

This OFC, all assumes you are still using `react-router-dom` v5 since you made no mention of any `Redirect` component import errors (*`Redirect` was removed in RRDv6*). If this isn't the case and you ***are*** actually using RRDv6 then please update your question to include a more complete code example.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I am using react-router-dom v5. I updated my question for it to be more clear

Comment: @YaraR Has this answer resolved your question/issue?